# Native perl hexdump -- just checking for zero values

Tags: perl, hexdump

I'm trying to check to see if a disk or disk image is 'empty'. I'm going to assume that this is true if the first 1mb and last 1mb are zeroes. I started by trying to recreate `hexdump` but it seems a little convuluded at this point.

Here's roughly my code:

```
open DISK, $disk or die $!;
for( 1 .. 1024 ) {
    $buffer = undef;
    sysread(DISK, $buffer, 1024, 0) or last;
    for ( split //, $buffer ) {
        if( ord($_) =~ /[^0]/ ) {
            $flag++;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check directly if the byte string `$buffer` contains anything other than `\0` bytes.

```
if ($buffer =~ /[^\0]/) {
    $flag++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a RE there? Can just do `ord($_) > 0`, no? Also, if all you care is flagging once you find a non-zero byte, just abort after you find it, and don't bother scanning the rest of the disk:

```
open DISK, $disk or die $!;
for( 1 .. 1024 ) {
    my $buffer = undef;
    sysread(DISK, $buffer, 1024, 0) or last;
    for ( split //, $buffer ) {
        if( ord($_) > 0 ) {
            die "Non-zero byte found";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Often when you find yourself running `split //` to produce a list of characters, there’s some better way to do this in Perl without resorting to chopping your strings up into little tiny — and separate — characters. The regex approach given by @mob is going to a couple of magnitudes faster than the slice-n-dice method you’re using.

Comment: Certainly, I was looking at way too focused a view there, trying to fix a step instead of rewriting the entire algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Why loop yourself? You can just use List::Util's `first` function.  It also short circuits.

```
use List::Util qw(first);
$flag++ if first { ord($_) > 0 } split(//, $buffer);
```